# extjs 4 gridpanel right border missing

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have the following problem, I defined a gridpanel with two columns, one with flex 3 and one with flex 1. the problem is that the surrounding container of the grid is exactly the same size as the table itself which make the right border disappear.

I can see in the html rendered that there is the table itself which is surrounded by some divs that are for some reason the same size and i can't change it.

Any thoughts?

Tahnks

Comment: I have had the same problem and I change the size in css. I take from firebug the id and add important to style like : #ext-2000{width:10px !important;}

Comment: but if you would re size the frame its in the width will not change accordingly

Comment: I change the width of the divs which have same size as the grid to one or two pixels more than grid width and I haven't saw any problem. (maybe I don't understand correctly your comment)

Comment: My grid panel sits inside a panel that is inside a region (that can be resized by the user), if  I set hard coded width value that layout will not change after resize

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin to the grid? Something like `margin: 0 2 0 0` in the grid configuration object?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `scroll` to `false` can fix you problem.

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    scroll: false


    // your code here

});
```